# Unable to use express-unless to exempt a few routes from authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am fairly new to js & nodejs. So, I tried to use *express-jwt* to authenticate most of my apis.

However, I want to exempt routes like **/login** and **/register** from authentication

Having gone through the documentation of *express-jwt*, I learnt that there is such a lib called *express-unless*

So, I mimicked the example to see if I can get it working. Here's code

```
const unless = require('express-unless');

app
  .use(authenticateWithExpressJWT)
  .unless({ path: ['/login'] });
```

**authenticateWithExpressJWT** is my middleware function which works fine

```
const jwt = require('express-jwt');

const verifyJwt = jwt({ secret: 'secreyKey', algorithms: ['HS256'] });

module.exports.authenticateWithExpressJWT = verifyJwt;
```

When I searched for examples on Google or Stackoverflow, it seems others don't seem to have any problem using similar code. However, when I do this, it doesn't even compile. I get this error

```
app.use(authenticateWithExpressJWT).unless({ path: ['/login'] });
                                    ^

TypeError: app.use(...).unless is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/xyz/programming/node/firstApp/index.js:27:37)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
```

Can somebody help me figure out what am I doing wrong ?

I have another question : How is that people are able to use `unless()` method without `require('express-unless');`?

I get the above mentioned compilation error irrespective of whether I add `const unless = require('express-unless');` or not

**Note**: **I understand that I can achieve the same without using `express-unless`. I am only keen to understand how I can use it.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally haven't worked with `express-unless`, but according to the docs, you should be able to do this, since `express-jwt` itself [supports](https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt#additional-options) `unless`:

```
const jwt = require('express-jwt');

const verifyJwt = jwt({ secret: 'secreyKey', algorithms: ['HS256'] })
                  .unless({path: ['/login'] });

module.exports.authenticateWithExpressJWT = verifyJwt;
```

In your app then just use your middleware:

```
app.use(authenticateWithExpressJWT)
```

Comment: Thank you very much !! You made my day.  It worked like charm Trying to call ```unless()``` on ``app``` from ```const app = express();``` was my mistake.  I should have called ```unless()``` on ```jwt``` from ```const jwt = require('express-jwt');```instead. 
 Thank you once again for showing what I was doing wrong in such an easy manner

Answer (score 1):

I normally exempt routes from auth by creating a function like as shown below.

```
function authJwt() {
return expressjwt({
    'secret',
    algorithms: ['HS256'],
    isRevoked: isRevoked,
}).unless({
    path: ['/login'],
});
}

async isRevoked(req, payload, done){
   // your code goes here for revoking
}
```

and then in your entry point (index.js/app.js), import the authJwt and use it in your entire app.

```
app.use(authJwt())
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same issue in think there is a issue with the latest version
so I use the "express-unless": "^1.0.0" .
it works well for me .

use this version of the package i think its quick fix for this issue

```
"express-unless":"^1.0.0"
```

Answer (score -2):

Use as below;
it will work. i found this from express-unless **github-readme** file

```js
const {unless} = require("express-unless");

    "functionName".unless = unless;
    app.use(
     "functionName".unless({
        path: "routes",
      })
    )
```

Comment: Hi, I downvoted your answer because 1)  there is an error, you are missng a closing ')', and 2) there is already an accepted answer that doesn't require taht module